# convert *.po file to *.pot

Tags: file-format

I need to convert *.PO file (binary gettext file), and I need to convert it to *.POT file(source gettext file), I did it via :

```
msgfilter -i my pofile.po -o mypot.pot true
```

But it didn't generate my translations, It only generate my msgid.

Question is How can I generate source gettext file via my *.po file without eliminating translations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*.PO is not compiled , if you want to generate compiled getetxt you can do the following commands:

```
msgcat related-fa_IR.pot | msgfmt -o related-fa_IR.mo -
```

OR

```
msgcat related-fa_IR.po | msgfmt -o related-fa_IR.mo -
```

*.mo is compiled file.